# Data is not saving in MEMORY table of HSQL

Tags: hsqldb

I have created a MEMORY table in HSQL. But the data is saved and accessed only in the running of my Java application.In HSql FAQ they said that,

```
...the default, MEMORY tables are persistent.
```

The data is not persistent after the program exists. What is the problem here?

SQL:

```
CREATE MEMORY TABLE SESSIONS(
    SESSION_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    IN_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    OUT_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)
```

Java :

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:"+
    DbConnection.class.getResource("/loginTimerDB").getPath()+"/loginTimerDB",
    "SA",
    "");
```

*I have placed this database file within java packages to make a simple jar file while deploying.*

Ok. at first I have the same thought about packing database in jar file. so I have moved that hsql database folder, to out side of the source packages. And, I have changed the java code like below,

```
"jdbc:hsqldb:file:loginTimerDB/loginTimerDB"
```

I have previously worked with hsql db, and never had a problem like this.

Comment: Please attach the JDBC URL you use to access the database. It all depends on this.

Answer (score 1):

When you put a database in a jar, it become readonly.

In your deployment, you can extract the database into a separate directory with read/write permissions before accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you closing the database before your application exits? Regarding to the [Hsqldb User Guide, Closing the Database](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N101DB), you have to send a `SHUTDOWN` command via the JDBC connection

```
connection.prepareStatement("SHUTDOWN").execute();
```

or set the `shutdown=true` property in the connection string:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:loginTimerDB/loginTimerDB;shutdown=true
```